# Spring ClientHttpRequestInterceptor body encoding

Tags: java, spring, encoding, character-encoding

I use the Spring 3.2.8 `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to modify the HTTP request send by `RestTemplate`. By overriding the method `intercept(HttpRequest, byte[], ClientHttpRequestExecution)` I get access to the request headers and body. The body is represented as a `byte` array.

My problem refers to the encoding of the `byte` content. It can contain german umlauts. The strings are correct encoded just before they are passed to the interceptor. Inside the interceptor method I tried to decode the body with `new String(body)` and the umlauts are substituted with unknown characters like this `��������`.

How can I keep the umlauts in the interceptor so that the request is properly coded? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is really simple. I have to force the UTF-8 encoding in the `byte` array to `String` conversion with:

```
new String(body, "UTF-8")
```

Now the result contains umlauts.